# "Can't contact LDAP server (-1)" error for LDAPS to Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, ldap

When attempting to connect to Active Directory on **Window Server 2012** (possibly R2) over **LDAPS**, ldapsearch produces one of the following errors (at the end of a longer output):

```
$ ldapsearch -H ldaps://my.ad.com -v -b "dc=my,dc=ad,dc=com"
...
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
    additional info: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
```

or

```
$ ldapsearch -H ldaps://my.ad.com -v -b "dc=my,dc=ad,dc=com" -D "user@my.ad.com"
...
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

or

```
$ ldapsearch -H ldaps://my.ad.com -d 1 -v -b "dc=my,dc=ad,dc=com" -D "user@my.ad.com" -W
...
TLS: can't connect: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received..
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

The SSL certificate has been installed and verified using s_client e.g.:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.ad.com:636 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

... which generates valid output ending in something like:

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Session-ID: 2938000006304A580F4FA7C47F3C0C64FCF43B83B666D24B247775E24DC6B5B1
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: C835DACE990D164C2F97F594B1D6989179735CE38AD822165F7C20C99C826DEE7E91816693AA72B08ADD85EDB6493578
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1490979674
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: When using ldapsearch, you generally need -v -d 2 to get useful SSL debugging.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur because the TLS 1.2 implementation in Windows 2012 is incompatible with some versions of Linux libraries like `gnutls`.

If this is your problem, disabling TLS 1.2 will restore functionality.  The following options may be available to you:

In Linux CLI (may need to escape the exclamation point, found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292281)):

```
export LDAPTLS_CIPHER_SUITE=NORMAL:!VERS-TLS1.2
```

In PHP on Linux (found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292281) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/33258ad8-2a6b-4421-9253-4e0bda459e7b/how-to-enable-tls-12-on-windows-server-2012-r2-for-ldaps-clients)):

```
putenv(‘LDAPTLS_CIPHER_SUITE=NORMAL:!VERS-TLS1.2’);
```

On Windows Server 2012, I can't find concise instructions, but these are the [registry entries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786418(v=ws.11).aspx).  Directly editing the registry can be dangerous so use with caution.