# GLPI + Docker : Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: php, docker, ldap

I'm trying to migrate our GLPI on Docker.

```
version: "3"
services:
    glpi1-front:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: glpi1_front
        build: ./glpi1_front
        volumes:
            - "/var/_prod/volumes/glpi1/glpi/files:/var/www/html/files:rw"
            - "/var/_prod/volumes/glpi1/glpi/config:/var/www/html/config:rw"
        networks:
            glpi1-front-mysql-network:
            proxy-network:
                aliases:
                    - "glpi1"
    glpi1-mysql:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: mariadb:latest
        networks:
            glpi1-front-mysql-network:
                aliases:
                    - "mysql"
        volumes:
            - "/var/_prod/volumes/glpi1/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
networks:
    glpi1-front-mysql-network:
    proxy-network:
        external:
            name: "reverse_proxy-glpi1-network"
```

- LDAP config works on dedicated server
- copied prod /var/lib/mysql in the container:  it's working
- config/config_db.php is ok (GLPI shows up so DB connection is ok)
- Domain controller pings
- TCPDUMP shows php reaching domain controller and DC replies

  09:20:24.474705 IP 192.168.96.3.52420 > 10.106.1.1.636: Flags [S], seq 979141056, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1691184423 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

  09:20:24.475006 IP 10.106.1.1.636 > 192.168.96.3.52420: Flags [S.], seq 3465462514, ack 979141057, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,sackOK,TS val 549593976 ecr 1691184423], length 0

  09:20:24.475027 IP 192.168.96.3.52420 > 10.106.1.1.636: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1691184423 ecr 549593976], length 0

  09:20:24.482416 IP 192.168.96.3.52420 > 10.106.1.1.636: Flags [P.], seq 1:338, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1691184431 ecr 549593976], length 337

  09:20:24.483234 IP 10.106.1.1.636 > 192.168.96.3.52420: Flags [P.], seq 1:1772, ack 338, win 8235, options [nop,nop,TS val 549593976 ecr 1691184431], length 1771
  [...]

But I still get the following error :

```
[2019-08-29 09:24:43] glpiphplog.ERROR: Toolbox::userErrorHandlerNormal() in /var/www/html/inc/toolbox.class.php line 659
  *** PHP Warning(2): ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server
  Backtrace :
  :
  inc/authldap.class.php:2575                        ldap_bind()
  inc/authldap.class.php:2604                        AuthLDAP::connectToServer()
  inc/auth.class.php:211                             AuthLDAP::tryToConnectToServer()
  inc/authldap.class.php:2723                        Auth->connection_ldap()
  inc/authldap.class.php:2778                        AuthLDAP::ldapAuth()
  inc/auth.class.php:757                             AuthLDAP::tryLdapAuth()
  front/login.php:84                                 Auth->login()
  {"user":"@75e0ec127885"}
[2019-08-29 09:24:43] glpiphplog.ERROR: Toolbox::userErrorHandlerNormal() in /var/www/html/inc/toolbox.class.php line 659
  *** PHP Warning(2): ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server
  Backtrace :
  :
  inc/authldap.class.php:2575                        ldap_bind()
  inc/authldap.class.php:2611                        AuthLDAP::connectToServer()
  inc/auth.class.php:211                             AuthLDAP::tryToConnectToServer()
  inc/authldap.class.php:2723                        Auth->connection_ldap()
  inc/authldap.class.php:2778                        AuthLDAP::ldapAuth()
  inc/auth.class.php:757                             AuthLDAP::tryLdapAuth()
  front/login.php:84                                 Auth->login()
  {"user":"@75e0ec127885","mem_usage":"0.003\", 1.76Mio)"}
```

TL;DR trafic goes through, but authentication does not work.

Comment: can you please get debug logs ? with something like ```ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);```, you are using port ```636 LDAPS``` im suspecting SSL verification problem here. I need debug logs to be sure

Comment: Yep : TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x142)

Comment: Followed instrucitons here [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/628777/cant-contact-ldap-server-with-ldaps-in-docker) . Please *post an answer* with this link since you lead me to this way and I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: You should post an answer yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't contact LDAP server (with ldaps) in Docker](https://serverfault.com/questions/628777/cant-contact-ldap-server-with-ldaps-in-docker)

Answer (score 0):

vx3r led me to check the cert problem, I found this post : [Can't contact LDAP server (with ldaps) in Docker](https://serverfault.com/questions/628777/cant-contact-ldap-server-with-ldaps-in-docker) , now it's working.